# Parsing a JSON file without arrays

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse this: https://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json for an Android app that shows the dollar to bolivar unofficial exchange rate.

I am using this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/, which I have used successfully before, however previous APIs I have used consisted of a JSON array with child objects. This one, however, has 12 JSON objects with strings. No square brackets to be seen.

The part (I think) I'm having trouble with is:

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
  try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

    // Getting JSON Array node
    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

    // looping through All Contacts
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

      String id = c.getString("id");
      String name = c.getString("name");
      String email = c.getString("email");
      String address = c.getString("address");
      String gender = c.getString("gender");

      // Phone node is JSON Object
      JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
      String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
      String home = phone.getString("home");
      String office = phone.getString("office");
    }
  } catch (final JSONException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                          "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                          .show();
        }
      });
   }
}
```

I'm no expert, since I'm trying to learn programming on my own and I'm still very new. However, I have made some changes including getting rid of the **ListView**, and adapting the code to the new JSON.

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
  try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

    // Getting JSON Object node
    JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject("USD");
    JSONObject d = jsonObj.getJSONObject("EUR");

    String usdtrans = c.getString("dolartoday");
    String usdreal = c.getString("efectivo_real");
    String usddicom = c.getString("sicad2");
    String eurtrans = d.getString("dolartoday");
    String eurreal = d.getString("efectivo_real");
    String eurdicom = d.getString("sicad2");
  }
  } catch (final JSONException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
         }
       });
   }
 }
```

The code does not compile, and Android Studio detects an `"unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException"`. What can I do to change this?

Any help would be appreciated. The rest of my code has other issues as well, but I think I can sort those out once I can get this one done.

Comment: You got unnecessary curly bracket before   `catch (final JSONException e) ` in your second code.

Comment: json: `"dolartoday": 1026.13`, 
code: ` String usdtrans = c.getString("dolartoday");`
The value of that json is not String. It is double. If you getString, it will be error.

Comment: No it won't. The double value will be converted to string and returned

Answer (score 0):

While using org.json library classes, If the JSON response consists of square bracket "[" then we need to get that element as JSONArray else get the element as JSONObject.

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        JSONObject antibloqueo = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_antibloqueo");
        JSONObject labels = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_labels");
        JSONObject timestamp = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_timestamp");
        JSONObject USD = jsonObject.getJSONObject("USD");
        JSONObject EUR = jsonObject.getJSONObject("EUR");
        JSONObject COL = jsonObject.getJSONObject("COL");
        JSONObject GOLD = jsonObject.getJSONObject("GOLD");
        JSONObject USDVEF = jsonObject.getJSONObject("USDVEF");
        JSONObject USDCOL = jsonObject.getJSONObject("USDCOL");
        JSONObject EURUSD = jsonObject.getJSONObject("EURUSD");
        JSONObject BCV = jsonObject.getJSONObject("BCV");
        JSONObject MISC = jsonObject.getJSONObject("MISC");


        //To get Values From antibloqueo
        String mobile = antibloqueo.getString("mobile");
        String video = antibloqueo.getString("video");


        //To get Values From labels
        String a = labels.getString("DOLARTODAY");
        String a1 = labels.getString("a1");


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

**Note:**
While working with smaller projects you can use org.json library as the JSON Convertor. For the bigger projects you have to use other libraries like Gson /Jackson

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: Great, I got that part sorted out, but now I have a couple of errors I didn't have before.

I'm getting an else without if error right below the new code. Don't know what would be wrong there since I have checked and yes, there's an if.

And I'm also getting "cannot resolve symbol result" on an onPostExecute variable. Don't know where I can paste the code in a comment

Comment: Sorry for taking long, here it goes: http://www.paste.org/81498

I based my code on this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/, which parses the code into a ListView. I don't want the ListView, since I want to parse the code into two simple TextViews, so I tried to remove it. This is why I think errors are coming out. Thanks for your help!